# WCF HTTP 504 Error

Tags: wcf, web-services, http, rest, web-config

I have the following problem. I am using Entity Framework to connect to a SQL Azure and that works(I tested it in a Test Project).

But when i try to get it through WCF RESTful service it throws Error 504.

My Operation Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Artikli", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    IEnumerable<Artikal> GetArtikli();
}
```

Implementation of `[ServiceContract]` :

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public IEnumerable<Artikal> GetArtikli()
    {
        using (var context = new CijenolomciEntities())
        {
            var result = context.Artikals.ToList();
            result.ForEach(a => context.Detach(a));
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

The whole thing is hosted on local IIS. I use Fiddler, an what it says when i try to reach

```
http://localhost:17916/Service.svc/Artikli
```

is

`[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.`

The WCF App.Config looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="CijenolomciEntities" connectionString="My_Connection_String" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        </connectionStrings>

        <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        </system.web>

        <system.serviceModel>
            <protocolMapping>
                <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding" />
            </protocolMapping>
            <behaviors>
                <endpointBehaviors>
                    <behavior>
                        <webHttp />
                    </behavior>
                </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        </system.serviceModel>

        <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```

**EDIT:**
When i try to access URL through browser i get the following:

```
Request Error

The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to enable [**Tracing**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) and see if your request is exceeding the default values due to which you are getting a timeout error.

Inspect the trace log for detailed error on why it is failing and then appropriately perform the needed steps to increase either the timeout values or the default size limits

Comment: Is it maybe because I don't have any endpoint specified in Web.config?

Answer (score 0):

If your network environment is set to make all HTTP traffic go through a proxy server then it's likely the account the IIS app pool is running under isn't allow to send HTTP traffic. As a test, change the app pool account to your login account and see if the WCF service connects successfully. The 504 message is usually a proxy or network issue.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how to do it?

Comment: Here is a [good article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/) on configuring accounts for IIS app pools. Just replace the current account with your login account and see if it works then.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is the network error. The issue is in the service. Might be you receive 504 not from IIS, but from Fiddler. [Read this](http://geekswithblogs.net/JamesFleming/archive/2011/03/09/wcf-http-504-working-on-a-mystery.aspx). Might be you have to increase  [maxItemsInObjectGraph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.maxitemsinobjectgraph.aspx)